# Using informats when creating a dataset from another dataset

Tags: sas

I've got a dataset that's full of data all in character format.

Now I want to create another dataset from this one, put put everything it it's correct decimal or date or character format.

Here's what I'm trying.

```
data work.testout;

    attrib account_open_date informat = mmddyy10.;


    do i = 1 to nobs; 
        set braw.accounts point = i nobs = nobs; 
        output; 




    end;
    stop;
run;
```

this gives me: 
`Variable 'account_open_date' from data set braw.accounts (at line 7 column 21) has a different type (character) to the variable type on the data vector (numeric)`

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you write your own datastep loop?  Does DATASERVER not have the normal SAS automatic datastep loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an informat to convert a variable directly from character to numeric.  At least in SAS proper, you cannot convert a variable from character to numeric, period, without using an intermediary.  You must do something along the lines of the following:

```
data want;
set have(rename=varwant=temp);
varwant=input(temp,MMDDYY10.);
drop temp;
run;
```

There you rename the (character) variable to a temporary name, then convert it to numeric using INPUT.

Comment: How would I do it if I want the format to be character?

`varwant = input(temp, $10);`

gives me: `ERROR: Parsing exception - aborting
ERROR: DS-00274 : Could not parse base DataServer code: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 25, column 88.
Was expecting one of:
    ";" ...
    "*" ...
    "**" ...
    "=" ...
    "<" ...
    (and 51 more)`

Comment: INPUT = takes a numeric or character input and returns numeric.  PUT = takes a numeric or character input and returns character.

Comment: @user1068446 If you are showing the code you tried exactly, the error message is caused because you failed to include a "dot" in the format spec.  Try `varwant = input(temp, $10.);`.  And read up a bit on SAS concepts; I think you are confusing SAS `formats` and `informats` with `data types`.  And the `INPUT` function will create either character or numeric variables (depending on the `informat` used) while the `PUT` function always creates character variables.